# How can I successfully add a new button to the top bar of Reddit new layout

Tags: javascript, reddit

I'm trying to create a user script to add a new button to the new Reddit design so I can return to the old layout easily.
The new button goes [somewhere around here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08L21.png)

**This is my simple code:**

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('s17th0jh-5 iAfVlC')

var bOld = document.createElement("button");
bOld.innerHTML = "old";
parent[0].appendChild(bOld);

bOld.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var url = document.URL;
  url = url.replace('/www.', '/old.');
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

The problem is, every time I load or reload the page the new button appears and quickly disappears within a second. How can I fix this?

Comment: try setting various CSS properties on `bOld ` and making them `!important`, might want to look at `display` (it could be changing to `none` and you would need `block`), `opacity` (it could be changing to `0` and you would need `1`) and `visibility` (it could be changing to `hidden` and you would need `visible`.

Comment: I can see your button when executing your code from the console on a reddit page. Do you have an error ?

Comment: @EdmundReed No, the element itself completely vanishes.

Comment: @SLePort This works fine when run in the console after page loading. The problem occurs only when the page loads and reloads.

Comment: @theAilurophile is the DOM element disappearing from the DOM? Is that what you mean by "vanishes"?

Comment: @EdmundReed Sorry about being vague before. Yes the DOM element disappears from the DOM.

Comment: Can you add your function in a `window.load` function or something? It sounds like reddit has some javascript which is executing after yours (which has a side effect of deleting your button). If you can get yours to execute after reddit's perhaps it would work?

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', function() { /*YOUR CODE*/ });`

Comment: @EdmundReed This actually worked! Thank You so much for your help.

Comment: @theAilurophile great :) I posted as an answer so you can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add your function in a window.load function or something? It sounds like reddit has some javascript which is executing after yours (which has a side effect of deleting your button). If you can get yours to execute after reddit's perhaps it would work?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { /*YOUR CODE*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because since reddit is using react , your changes are getting overwritten due to re - rendering. Because after your script executes the component gets re - rendered. 
But the solution to this problem is using `setTimeout` .In this, after the component/header is done rendering , your script will then append your button/link

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('s17th0jh-5 iAfVlC')

var bOld = document.createElement("button");
bOld.innerHTML = "old";
setTimeout(function(){
    parent[0].appendChild(bOld);

    bOld.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var url = document.URL;
        url = url.replace('/www.', '/old.');
        window.location.href = url;
    });
},1000)
```